# How can I find a sheet by name and delete it via Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a workbook with lots of sheets, each titled as someone's last name. Ex. Jones, Smith, and Williams each have a sheet.

I've written a script, and based on a prompt where I put in the person's name when I run the script, I would like to delete their sheet in my workbook. With the current script I have, I have an error when I run.

Any help?

```
function DeleteEmployee() {
//Enter employee's name
 var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Daily Overview")
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response = ui.prompt('First Name', 'Please enter the first name of the employee', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
 var FirstName = response.getResponseText();

 var ui2 = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response2 = ui2.prompt('Last Name', 'Please enter the last name of the employee', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
 var LastName = response2.getResponseText();

  //Deletes the employee's sheet 
 var Source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(LastName).deleteActiveSheet();

}
```

Comment: Please include the error :)

Comment: Also, what is the format of the sheet names? When you search for the sheet to delete, you only search for `LastName`, when you ask the user for "First Name" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You try to find the sheet with only the last name; I would assume with employee records, their first name is also there? Assuming sheets are named in **"LastName, FirstName"** format, you can use/adjust the following:

```
var Source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(LastName + ", " + FirstName);
```

2) The documentation for [`deleteSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteSheet(Sheet)) shows that it's a function of the `Speadsheet` object, not the `Sheet` object, and you'd need to pass in the sheet object. So you would have to call it like this:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(Source);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function DeleteEmployee() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Daily Overview")
 var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response=ui.prompt('First Name', 'Please enter the first name of the employee', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
 var FirstName=response.getResponseText();
 response=ui.prompt('Last Name', 'Please enter the last name of the employee', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
 var LastName=response.getResponseText();
 var sheet=ss.getSheetByName(LastName);
 ss.deleteSheet(sheet)
}
```